# Reuse of keep-alive HTTP web request object

Tags: c#, .net, http, httpwebrequest, keep-alive

Lets say I want to send 10 requests where each has different URI (same host, but different resource) and I want to reuse the connection in a way that first request creates keep-alive persistent connection which is reused by the following 9 requests. Using WebRequest.Create seems to dedicate the request to specific resource, therefore there needs to be 10 `HttpWebRequest` objects where each of them is sent with keep-alive header. How does .NET framework reuse HTTP keep-alive connections created with [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y7x3zz2.aspx) class and [KeepAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive.aspx) property? Does it work transparently or the request object needs to be reused manually in code?

Comment: I like your profile pic very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking for a solution to the same problem. As far as I can tell it is not possible because `request.RequestURI` is just readonly.

My Solution would be to call a "general" front controller with a POST parameter including the wanted command. This controller then calls the wanted command and proxies the response back to you. So you just need to change a POST parameter instead of the whole url.